# CropperJS: Image outsite the crop box is not visible

Tags: javascript, cropper

I am using javascript [cropperjs](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper) to crop images uploaded by the user. In the cropper display, the image outside the crop-box is not visible. A sample in shown in the below image -

[image]

My cropper config is -

```
var cropper_opts = {
  aspectRatio: 1/1,
  viewMode: 0,
  crop: function(e){}, //to show the crop box manually
  minCanvasWidth: 0,
  minCanvasHeight: 0,
  minCropBoxWidth: 0,
  minCropBoxHeight: 0,
  minContainerWidth: 860,   //decides the size of image
  minContainerHeight: 355,  //decides the size of image
  autoCropArea: 1,
  modal: true,      // Show the black modal
  guides: true,     // Show the dashed lines for guiding
  center: true,     // Show the center indicator for guiding
  highlight: true,  // Show the white modal to highlight the crop box
  background: true, // Show the grid background
}
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably happening because you are using cropper inside some sort of html template that already has cropper integrated and the canvas element already has some other style applied.

Inspect this class **.cropper-canvas**

In my case I found that the template I was using set its opacity to 0.

```
.cropper-canvas {
  cursor: crosshair;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0; /* that's the problem */
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```